# transform existed usual forms to angularJs'ed

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In existed project I would like to take usual html form, add a directive to it and get angular-powered form. Actually, the task is to take this:

```
<form name="myOlfForm" transform>
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />
    <button type"submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

and transform it into this in runtime:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myOlfForm.foo"/>
    <button type"submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I use compile function of the directive to transform inputs' names to ng-model attributes. Seems all works like expected, but the issue is how to add ng-submit directive to the form (we can not be sure there are submit button in a form exists, it may be submitted by keypress or by code, so it should be bind to onsubmit event, like ng-submit does)

Here is jsFiddle to illustrate http://jsfiddle.net/dbwTr/1/

Comment: Why do you want to use ng-submit directly within your directive? It would make more sense to pass it through: <form transform ng-submit="submit()">

Comment: If it can be automated, why dont we want to do that :)

Comment: Your directive transform seems to be reusable on any form. Normally forms has different models and usually different submit functionality. So it would imho be better to keep your models and functions (some se $scope.fn() as a Part of the model too) in your controllers. It will also keep your code more consistent :)